# Cannot determine wordpress sidebar content is coming from

Tags: php, wordpress

I inherited this project and the original designer is long gone.  And I'm not super familiar with Wordpress.

On [this page](http://coloradohypnosis.com.s51572.gridserver.com/medical-hypnosis/) I don't know how this sidebar is being generated.  I `grep`'ed the entire directory looking for content such as "Bill Johnson" or "Rocky Mountain News" but it's not in the Wordpress files.  So, it has to be part of the database.

But the site has no widgets or posts.  Under Pages, I don't see an option to include a sidebar.

Here's code in the wp-content/themes directory.

sidebar.php:
`<?php print get_post_meta($post->ID, "sidebar_var", true); ?>`

page.php:

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="left">

    <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
            <?php the_content('Read the rest of this entry &raquo;'); ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php else : ?>
        <p>Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.</p>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <!-- End #left --><br class="cl" /></div>

<?php get_sidebar();?>

  <!-- End #content --><br class="cl" /></div>

<?php get_footer();?>
```

Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: looking at your page source it looks like it might be hard-coded in.  have you looked in get_sidebar(); to see if it might be there?

Comment: As you can read from the Codex (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta), `get_post_meta` gets content from custom fields. Try going to that page in wordpress' backoffice, probably there's some custom fields there with that information.

Comment: Post the contents of sidebar.php. That's more than likely where your HTML on the right side is being generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Cthulhu's suggestion, inspecting the database, there's a record in the `wp_postmeta` table with the `meta_key` field set to value `sidebar_var`.  The `meta_value` field of the same record has the sidebar html.  Not sure why the original designer did it this way, but I will refactor to use widgets.